# Соединение с mysql через туннель SSH используя php

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных, mysqli, ssh

Доброго времени суток. Возникла следующая загвоздка:

Использую для работы windows с установленным WAMP. Поставщик услуг хостинга позволяет подключаться к бд только по SSH2 (оно и правильно), вот только подключиться к базе не удаётся. Делаю следующее

```
$ssh_server='93.125.xx.xx'; //адрес сервера
$ssh_port='22'; //порт сервера
$ssh_user=''; //логин от сервера
$ssh_password=''; //пароль от сервера

$ssh_connection=ssh2_connect($ssh_server, $ssh_port);
$ssh_auth=ssh2_auth_password($ssh_connection, $ssh_user, $ssh_password);
$ssh_tunnel = ssh2_tunnel($ssh_connection, $ssh_server, $ssh_port);
```

Тут всё проходит на ура. Дальше проверяю и пробую подключиться к БД. Но так и не понял, как используя туннель созданный подключаться

```
if ($ssh_connection and $ssh_auth and $ssh_tunnel) {
    $db_hostname = '127.0.0.1';
    $db_database = ''; //имя БД mysql
    $db_username = ''; //имя пользоватля БД
    $db_password = ''; //пароль пользователя БД
    $db_port = '3306';

    $connection_mysql = new mysqli($db_hostname, $db_username, $db_password, $db_database, $db_port);
    if ($connection_mysql->connect_error) exit($connection_mysql->connect_error);
    mysqli_set_charset($connection_mysql, "utf8"); 
}
```

Выдаёт ошибку подключения стандартную

> Access denied for user 'igcby_gpresults'@'localhost' (using password:
>   YES)

Но судя по всему он коннектится просто к моей локальной базе данных, а у меня на машине такой нет.

Если же попробовать подставить в качестве `$db_hostname` переменные ssh, то тоже ничего путёвого не выходит. Для переменных $ssh_connection, $ssh_auth, $ssh_tunnel выдаёт, соответственно:

> mysqli::__construct() expects parameter 1 to be string, resource given
>
> mysqli::__construct(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed
>
> mysqli::__construct() expects parameter 1 to be string, resource given

var_dump трёх переменных ssh

```
var_dump($ssh_connection);
var_dump($ssh_auth);
var_dump($ssh_tunnel);
```

выдаёт следующее

> resource(2) of type (SSH2 Session)
>
> bool(true)
>
> resource(3) of type (stream)

Если же в качестве `$db_hostname` указывать непосредственно сам адрес сервера, как при подключении по ssh ($ssh_server='93.125.xx.xx'; и сделать также `$db_hostname='93.125.xx.xx';`), то толку тоже не будет (mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/2002): и куча ромбов с вопросами - что-то с кодировкой)

Как быть, подскажите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял то надо так:

1. Создать туннель.
2. Сделать порт forwarding с удаленной машины на локальную.
3. Запросы делать к локальному порту.

Простой вариант(для линукса):

```
<?php
    shell_exec(“ssh -f -L 3307:127.0.0.1:3306 user@remote_server sleep 60 >> logfile”);
    $db = mysqli_connect(‘127.0.0.1’, ‘sqluser’, ‘sqlpassword’, ‘database’, 3307);
```

Взят отсюда https://blog.rjmetrics.com/2009/01/06/php-mysql-and-ssh-tunneling-port-forwarding/

Не уверен как оно будет работать с `ssh2`
И если верить https://stackoverflow.com/questions/309615/connect-to-a-mysql-server-over-ssh-in-php то, ни как не будет.

Ну и страница проекта утверждает что библиотека не стабильна...

Как вариант для пользователя windows. Создайте туннель в putty.

http://www.akadia.com/services/ssh_putty.html

Привяжите на локальный порт  `3037`

А ваш код прост станет:

```
<?php
    $db = mysqli_connect(‘127.0.0.1’, ‘sqluser’, ‘sqlpassword’, ‘database’, 3307);
```

У `putty` есть интерфейс через командную строку нак что вполне можно использовать `shell_exec`.

У меня один вопрос, зачем вам это? Зачем с локального компьютера к базе удаленной подключаться?

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Завтра попробую. Дело в том, что у нас на локальной машине крутится БД с пользовательски интерфейсом через браузер по лакальной сети. Также есть сайт, где можно онлайн проверить готовность заказов. Потому нужно выгружать из локальной базы статусы готовности в базу на сайте. Вот так вот. Сейчас всё работает (использую какую-то бесплатную оооочень глюченую базу для этого без заморочек с SSH). Но раз есть у нас нормальный хостинг, то хочу использовать его базу. Однако можно с ней только по SSH. Вот так.

Comment: На той машине стоит Ubuntu. Буду сразу там и пробовать. Хотел дома всё отладить и испытать, но видно нужно сразу всё делать на линуксе.

Comment: @n.osennij `sleep 60` -> туннель будет жить минуту. Если надо больше увеличивайте значение.

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте
$connection_mysql = new mysqli($db_hostname, $db_username, $db_password, $db_database, $db_port, $ssh_tunnel);

Comment: Ошибка mysqli::__construct() expects parameter 6 to be string, resource given